# access server URL subdomain in meteor mobile app

Tags: javascript, meteor

If my Meteor app is live on `www.example.com`, I can access the subdomain with `location.hostname`:

```
Template.name.helpers({
    subdomain: () => location.hostname.split('.').shift(),
});
```

So that this page:

```
<p>You are on {{subdomain}}</p>
```

Will say "You are on www".

Then I can build a test app with this command:

```
$ meteor run ios --mobile-server=www.localhost:3000
```

And in this app, the `subdomain` helper simply returns `localhost`. I assume that is the same if I run this:

```
$ meteor build --server www.example.com
```

How do I find `www` (or whatever the subdomain is that I passed in the `server` flag) from my front end meteor code?